# Could you help me understand this Java code?

Tags: eclipse, android-studio

```
  @Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    addListenerOnButton();
}
```

This is the code I have when starting an Android project, I don't understand the code, could someone please help me understand it line by line?

Comment: What are you stuck on in particular? Whilst some people are willing to explain each line, we do need to guard against the possibility that posts of this kind are just being lazy. If you can edit in what you have found _yourself_ on this subject, that would be great.

Answer (score 1):

- `public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) { }`

In android every `Activity` you make is started through a sequence of lifecycle methods. `onCreate()` is the first of these calls.
Each `Activity` extends `Activity` either directly or by subclassing another subclass of `Activity`(`AppCompactActivity`).

- `super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);`

When you extend a class, you can override its methods to run your own code in them.
By calling `super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);`, you tell the Dalvik VM to run your code in addition to the existing code in the `onCreate()` of the parent class. If you leave out this line, then only your code is run. The existing code is ignored.

- `setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);`

`Activity` uses `setContentView(R.layout.main)` to set xml layout to that activity which will actually render as the UI of your activity.